# Content not appearing below my image slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

Using the help of w3schools and few other resources I managed to code a responsive image slider however I can't show any content below the image slideshow. It just doesn't appear. You can see in the code the fill-in paragraph. That doesn't appear. I tried without content div class and with. I know it's not the paragraph itself cause it works on other pages completely okay.

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img1/img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img1/img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img1/img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 9000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
            <div class="header">
<h1>yeet</h1>
 <p>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

            The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
```

and css

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}


.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.dot {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 9.6s ease;
}

.active {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

Comment: Is above HTML code complete?

Answer (score 2):

The `height` of your slide-container is 0.
The images inside have their own height, and cover the text below.
If you remove the `height: 0;` from `.slide-container`, the paragraph will show.

```
.slideshow-container {
  height: 0; /* <-- Remove this line */
}
```